# What does "dog-and-cat heaven" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Sweet Smell of Success* (1957), J.J and Falco confronts Dallas,
who hates Falco's presence:

> J.J: Why do you keep coupling me with Falco?
>
> Dallas: Why is he here? Tell me, sir: When he dies, do you think he'll go
> to the **dog-and-cat heaven**?

What does "dog-and-cat heaven" mean?

Comment: It's the same as the people heaven but for cats and dogs. If "he" is a person, then the remark is facetious.

Comment: Is Dallas comparing Falco has mindset of cats and dogs?

Comment: Perhaps that is the inference. I haven't read the story, so I don't know the context.

Comment: Dallas is sarcastically suggesting that JJ believes that Falco will go to the childish fantasy fairytale 'heaven' where pets, which are totally innocent, are imagined to go after they die. Falco is a deeply, utterly, immoral character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Dog heaven" (etc) is something you might say to a child whose pet has died

> Don't cry sweetheart, Binky is in dog heaven now.

So this is an insult. Dallas is implying that Falco is childish and not ready to deal with the harsh realities of life.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140055/discussion-on-answer-by-james-k-what-does-dog-and-cat-heaven-mean).